# Mocked private method getting invocked Jmockito

Tags: java, powermock, jmockit

I am writing a test case for my class using mockito and Power Mockito. for one of my public method i wrote the test case but that internally calling a private method, but i dont care about the result of private method so i decided to mock the method using Power Mockito as below

```
PowerMockito.doReturn(refDataListVO).when(mockObject,
            "referenceDataValues",Mockito.anyList(),(ReferenceDataListVO)anyObject());
```

My referenceDataValues method is as below

```
private ReferenceDataListVO referenceDataValues(List inputList,
            ReferenceDataListVO referenceDataListVO) {
   // Some Code
}
```

But when i run this code referenceDataValues method getting invoked.

Please help me on this

Comment: Why are you mocking a private method? If you mock a private method of your unit under test, what are you actually testing? I only mock the public API of collaborators of my unit under test.

Comment: I am actually testing the validation part in public method, the private method has the service calls which i dont want to test

Comment: Then you should mock the calls to the service methods, not your private method.

Comment: If you are writing new code as opposed to modifying existing code, then I recommend using JMock instead of Mockito. Here's why: http://blog.thecodewhisperer.com/2010/10/05/jmock-v-mockito-but-not-to-the-death/